# How to authenticate a device using pin code in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Firebase and I was wondering if the following is possible: I would like to be able to authenticate on a new device using a 4 or 6 digit pin code. Basically a quick way to add a device that is logged in.
From what I can see from the docs this is not a built-in functionality, but maybe someone has created something like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already discovered, signing in with only a PIN-code/password is not a built-in authentication method for Firebase. If you want to allow something like this in your app, you can [build a custom auth provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth) for it.

If you're targeting iOS, the Firebase SDKs have the ability to [synchronize a user's login state across all Apple user's devices](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/6924), which accomplishes a similar use-case without requiring a separate PIN